# Repeating overridden elements in ArrayList at the end

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

I know this question has been often repeated - but mine does not have any resemblance with existing reported issues !! :(  Mine there is no static fields and is in Spring framework platform app. Request assistance in the matter ..

As you see the console output given, the Array List repeatedly prints last item when I loop back the Array List contents

Here are my code snippet the culprit one :)

```
for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<String>> entry : fileDataCollection
            .entrySet()) {
        rowDataHolder=getRowDataBucket();    // Spring Based 
        int currrentRowIndex = entry.getKey();
        if ((currrentRowIndex > startRange) && currrentRowIndex < endRange) {

         List<String> rowDataValue=entry.getValue();

             if(null!=(rowDataValue)){
                SectionDataVO rowDataHolder=extractSectionSpecificData(entry.getValue());
                if(null!=rowDataHolder){
                                    System.out.println("Now Adding rowDataHolder Value");
                System.out.println("----"+rowDataHolder);
                DTOCollectionList.add(rowDataHolder);
                }


            }
```

Now my System out println for rowDataHolder  shows clearly it collects unique SectionDataVO every time. However when I try to add them in another ArrayList - it just add last one but thrice !! There is no static field here - all are spring based beans. I searched the here a lot of options given .. wondering what next to be done...

Console Output :

Now Adding rowData to List -

> > > TransSummaryDataVO [transactionName= 01_C01_OMS_AddNote, min= 0.061, avg= 0.138, max= 25.607, stdDeviation= 0.725, ninetyPerc= 0.16]
> > >
> > > TransSummaryDataVO [transactionName= 02_C01_OMS_GetNote, min= 0.09, avg= 0.374, max= 26.003, stdDeviation= 0.801, ninetyPerc= 0.404]
> > >
> > > TransSummaryDataVO [transactionName= OMSWillingToWait, min= 0.062, avg= 0.249, max= 64.869, stdDeviation= 2.441, ninetyPerc= 0.156]
>
> DTOCollectionList Size
>
> > > [TransSummaryDataVO [transactionName= OMSWillingToWait, min= 0.062, avg= 0.249, max= 64.869, stdDeviation= 2.441, ninetyPerc= 0.156], TransSummaryDataVO [transactionName= OMSWillingToWait, min= 0.062, avg= 0.249, max= 64.869, stdDeviation= 2.441, ninetyPerc= 0.156], TransSummaryDataVO [transactionName= OMSWillingToWait, min= 0.062, avg= 0.249, max= 64.869, stdDeviation= 2.441, ninetyPerc= 0.156]]
>
> Reading DTOCollectionList
>   ----------------------Reading Transaction Summary Section ------------------------------
>
> Now of Rows Data Recived 3
>
> > > TransSummaryDataVO [transactionName= OMSWillingToWait, min= 0.062, avg= 0.249, max= 64.869, stdDeviation= 2.441, ninetyPerc= 0.156]
> > >
> > > TransSummaryDataVO [transactionName= OMSWillingToWait, min= 0.062, avg= 0.249, max= 64.869, stdDeviation= 2.441, ninetyPerc= 0.156]
> > >
> > > TransSummaryDataVO [transactionName= OMSWillingToWait, min= 0.062, avg= 0.249, max= 64.869, stdDeviation= 2.441, ninetyPerc= 0.156]
> > >       Test App Beans Initiated ..

Comment: What happening ? Is your if-else not working/

Comment: Oh Sorry - I missed the exact problem.. As you see the console output given, the Array List repeatedly prints last item when I loop back the Array List contents. Just before adding to arraylist, I make sure the SectionDataVO are different -which is yes (as you see the printout line before adding to the ArrayList.

Comment: After a deep research -  I applied a cloning of objects using SerializationUtils.clone .. and which fetch me now data as expected. .. But still am wondering what is the reason behind ...the issue..

Comment: If you solved your problem, consider posting your solution as an answer so future readers can benefit from it.